# Delayed esc from insert mode caused by cursor-shape terminal sequence

Tags: terminal, cursor

I set a couple terminal options so that Vim changes the cursor shape to a vertical bar when I enter Insert mode, an underbar for Replace mode, and a block when I return to Normal mode:

```
let &t_SI="\<Esc>[6 q"
let &t_SR="\<Esc>[4 q"
let &t_EI="\<Esc>[0 q"
```

If `'ttimeoutlen'` has a high enough setting, there's a noticeable delay when leaving Insert mode, because you type <kbd>Escape</kbd> and Vim waits to see if it was the beginning of an `<Esc>[0 q` sequence. It waits `'ttimeoutlen'` milliseconds before deciding the `<Esc>` was an actual <kbd>Escape</kbd> keypress.

I usually keep `'ttimeoutlen'` set at 5, so it's not really noticeable. But I was also curious to try a "sledgehammer" workaround:

```
inoremap <Esc> <Esc><Esc>
```

and it works. Even more interesting is this works as well:

```
inoremap <Esc> <Esc>
```

I guess because Vim knows the right-hand-side of a mapping is the result of a keypress, not an input keycode, so it doesn't apply `'ttimeoutlen'` (but would apply `'timoutlen'` if you had other `imap`s that started with `<Esc>`).

It seems a little weird, but I'm having a hard time thinking of any downside this approach could have. I plan on keeping my `'ttimeoutlen'` low anyway, but maybe this could shave a couple extra milliseconds off the delay? Not that I'll actually notice :P

Is there any reason not to do this? What could it break?

Or is there a better solution altogether that I've missed? I suspect the answer is to just leave `'ttimeoutlen'` set to a low number and forget about it, but I am curious if anyone else has found different solutions.

---

*Update*:
I found a caveat to this approach. The `imap` effects escaping from Insert and Replace modes, and you can do the same for Visual mode with `vmap`, but none of these affects the timeout when canceling an `r` command in Normal mode using <kbd>Escape</kbd>.

It still seems like a useful hack -- escaping from an `r` command is a corner case -- but it's not a full solution.

---

*Update-2*: I found what this breaks. If you want to use a Meta/Alt key in an `imap`, e.g. `inoremap <M-d> foo`, the `inoremap <Esc> <Esc>` breaks that functionality because `<M-d>` consists of an Escape byte (`0x1b`) followed by the D byte. To take it to the extreme, imagine you'd defined a mapping:

```
inoremap <M-d>d bar
```

Typing `<M-d>d` in insert mode would end up deleting the current line! That's a corner case, but mapping Meta/Alt keys is not, so this is enough to convince me that `imap`ping `<Esc>` to itself is a bad idea. It is, after all, a hack.

The above won't apply if your terminal runs in 8-bit mode, since Alt/Meta will be represented by the high-bit instead of a leading Esc byte, but on 7-bit terminals (gnome-terminal, alacritty, etc.) it does apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the cursor shaping.

The whole reason the timeout settings exist is for the reason you found out in `Update-2` -- some keys that you type send a byte sequence that starts with an `<Esc>`.  This includes alt mappings, arrow keys, function keys, mouse interaction, etc.

Since most terminals aren't running in 8-bit mode, you're going to encounter a delay when typing `<Esc>`.  Of course, nothing requires you to wait for that delay.  If you just continue typing, you'll perform the same disambiguation that Vim is waiting for.

Since 8-bit mode isn't typical, it follows that mapping `<Esc>` is a terrible idea.  That's going to interfere with more than just `<Alt-...>` mappings.  The common workaround is to do exactly as you've suggested and reduce the timeout.  This has even been [adopted](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/e07e797db0c5ef1aafc650d8bb0d39fb052cf1e1) in defaults.vim.